# LinkedBlockingQueue nested under synchronized, livelock issue

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

considering the following lines

```
public Result doSomething(Service srv) throws InterruptedException 
{
    synchronized(srv)
    {
        if (this._registeredServices.containsKey(srv.getId()))
        {
            return this._queue.get(srv.getId()).take();
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}
```

where `this._queue` is implemented with

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, LinkedBlockingQueue<Result>> _queue;
```

couple of threads are accessing the `srv` from different places using the synchronized of course.

My question is, can I get into livelock wheras the `take` method is waiting for data and still holding the `srv` lock, or it releases it until it has a value and to take and then trying to get a grip of it again before continuing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lock on `srv` isn't released anywhere inside the synchronized block. The `LinkedBlockingQueue` doesn't know anything about it existing, and can do nothing about it. If the `take()` blocks, then another thread calling with the same `srv` will block on the `synchronized(srv)`. It would block on the `take()` as well eventually though.

The code looks unnecessarily complex by the way.